# What's the best way to telnet from a remote Windows PC without using RDP?

Tags: remote, telnet, pstools, plink

Three Networks:

1. 10.1.1.0 - Mine
2. 172.1.1.0 - My Branch Office
3. 172.2.2.0 - My Branch Office's VOIP VLAN.

My PC is on 10.1.1.0. I need to telnet into a Cisco router on 172.2.2.0. The 10.1.1.0 network has no routes to 172.2.2.0, but a VPN connects 10.1.1.0 to 172.1.1.0. Traffic on 172.1.1.0 can route to 172.2.2.0.

All PCs on 172.1.1.0 are running Windows XP. Without disrupting anyone using those PCs, I want to open a telnet session from one of those PCs to the router on 172.2.2.0.

I've tried the following:

```
psexec.exe \\branchpc telnet 172.2.2.1


psexec.exe \\branchpc cmd.exe
telnet 172.2.2.1


psexec.exe \\branchpc -c plink -telnet 172.2.2.1
```

Methods 1 and 2 both failed because telnet.exe is not usable over psexec. Method 3 actually succeeded in creating the connection, but I cannot login because the session registers my carriage return twice. My password is always blank because at the "Username:" prompt I'm effectively typing: Routeruser[ENTER][ENTER]

It's probably time to deploy WinRM...

Does anyone know of any other alternatives?

Does anyone know how I can fix plink.exe so it only receives one carriage return when I use it over psexec?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/), a revised version of [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)

```
psexec.exe \\branchpc -c ncat -t 172.2.2.1 23
```

This should do the trick, (`-t` to use "telnet mode"). If it doesn't work, you can use ncat for portforwarding with:

```
psexec.exe \\branchpc -c ncat -l -e -p 23 "ncat 172.2.2.1 23"
```

You can then telnet to your `\\branchpc` and will be forwarded to the router.
Be aware that this solution will make it possible for anyone that can connect to `\\branchpc`, to access the telnet port on the router as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not telnet to the router on network 172.1.1.0 and then telnet from that router to the router on network 172.2.2.0?

Comment: The router on 172.1.1.0 is a PIX 501e. I could be wrong, but I don't think it's possible to telnet from this device.