# Redirect telnet "interactivity" from host 3 to host 1 through host 2 (proxy?)

Tags: windows, telnet, pstools, netcat

My network configuration:

- *host 1* [h1] - User machine connected via VPN to the main host (host 2). (Win 7)
- *host 2* [h2] - The gate through other machines of my network. No firewall, no ip rules. (Win XP)
- *host 3* [h3] - The target machine. (Win XP)

From *h1* I'm able to connect via telnet to *h2* or start a cmd line session with `psexec`. From *h2* I can do the same pointing at *h3*. Now I would like to start a `telnet` session from h2 to h3, redirect the interactive output to h1 and send back input from h1 to h3.

What have I done:

- suggestions taken from: [What's the best way to telnet from a remote Windows PC without using RDP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/217471/whats-the-best-way-to-telnet-from-a-remote-windows-pc-without-using-rdp)
- h2 cmd started on h1 console through psexec command, `ncat` on h3 through h2 remote cmd line with empty line (return) as result.

I know psexec + telnet is not possible and netcat should be a good alternative, but it seems unable to handle prompt interactivity. Ideas?

Comment: There isn't really "interactivity"; telnet merely sends characters back and forth.  Generally a program that automates interaction with a telnet interface (or similar) expecting interactive input is called an expect script; take a look at methods used to write those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ssh for windows, but it requires additional software like cygwin which you mightn't need.

Try [Zedebee](http://www.winton.org.uk/zebedee/), it's a simple secure IP tunnel.

It runs well on windows and unix systems.

And it's a snap to setup.

Install it on hosts 1 & 2.

on h2 run:

```
zedebee -s host3:telnet
```

on h1 run:

```
zedebee host2 host3:telnet
```

It will print a port number.

then on h1 run:

```
telnet localhost <port>
```

Comment: Clean, simple and absolutely awesome! +1 and marked as answer!